# Can you have a SQL Server job with parameters?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Here is one job step:

```
\\server-sql\c$\BWServer\SFTPGETCONSOLEPARMS\SFTPGetConsole.exe "2|3"
```

But this never works in the SQL Server Agent job, nor do these: but they all work when running manually that same link with parameter.

Can you pass a parameter to a SQL Server job at all? What is wrong in these?

```
 \\server-sql\c$\BWServer\SFTPGETCONSOLEPARMS\SFTPGetConsole.exe "2"

\\server-sql\c$\BWServer\SFTPGETCONSOLEPARMS\SFTPGetConsole.exe "3"
```

Comment: why should it be a sql job? did you try with windows Schedule Task?

Comment: are you familiar with how to pass parameters to the command line in a console app..? also you know you can pass parms to your console app from the projects properties window 
`In Project Properties dialog, on Debug tab you can define command line arguments and working directory.`

Comment: ok i had thought that you pass in the agent job, in the steps like this\\server-sql\c$\BWServer\SFTPGETCONSOLEPARMS\SFTPGetConsole.exe "2|3" where 2 and 3 are the values being passed. I am mostly familiar with sql job and not other methods.